# Are version and name fields truly required in all package.json files?

Tags: npm, package.json

The package.json [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file#required-name-and-version-fields) say:

> A **package.json** file must contain **"name"** and **"version"** fields.

This is also mentioned [here](https://npm.github.io/using-pkgs-docs/package-json/using-a-packagejson.html).

I can see why that would be a requirement for node modules that are published to the registry, but is that still a hard requirement for private packages that are built and then deployed to customers?

It seems like I can remove both of those fields from my private module, but I want to verify that nothing will go wrong. If I'm never executing `npm publish`, then `npm` won't care about my versionless package, but maybe something else makes a big deal about it.

I'm guessing the docs should just be updated to reflect that it's a requirement *only* for node modules that are published.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a line from another [package.json doc page](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-json#name):

> If you plan to publish your package, the *most* important things in your package.json are the name and version fields as they will be required.

So, I think this means they are only required when publishing.